# Codeigniter ajax post the action you requested is not allowed

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to call the ajax once user had `onclick` on the button, then the button will be passing the id to the controller to output the result in my modal's div. However when I debug it show me the action you requested is not allowed.

Is there anything I can do about it on my code?

**View :**

```html
<input type="" name="" value="VIEW" class="btn btn-primary m-t-15 waves-effect" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#defaultModal" onclick="refresh_detail('.$row["Task_ID"].')">
```

**jQuery / AJAX Code:**

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
  function refresh_detail(id){
    $.ajax({
      url : "<?= base_url()?>admin/Admintask/get_task_detail",
      type : "POST",
      dataType : "json",
      data : {"TaskID" : id},
      success : function(data) {
        // do something
      },
      error : function(data) {
        // do something
      }
    });
  }
</script>
```

**Controller :**

```php
public function get_task_detail(){
  echo $this->input->post('TaskID');
}
```

Comment: What CI version are you using? IF it is CI4, share your router file.

Comment: @mail2bapi you mean the location route of my file?

Comment: Version is 3.1.6

Comment: show us your full code with view..

Comment: `echo` between `<?= echo base_url()?>`

Comment: @KUMAR i had edit my post

Comment: the content of your router file

Comment: @mail2bapi what is the need of route file??

Comment: use `echo` between `<?= echo base_url()?>`

Comment: @KUMAR what u mean echo between <?= echo base_url()?>

Comment: in url of ajax request..

Comment: @KUMAR You don't need to use echo when using a short echo tag. Learn more here https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php

Comment: @Marcus Did you JS made AJAX call to your server? if yes, what was the response from server?

Comment: @mail2bapi i getting forbiden error 403 due to the csrf_protection i guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Marcus as you are getting 403 due to CSRF Protection, you can add the URI to "csrf_exclude_uris" in the config.php file.
Steps:

1. Open your "**application/config/config.php**"
2. Goto line 457 or where it written **$config['csrf_exclude_uris'] = array();**
3. Add your URI in the array, like

   `$config['csrf_exclude_uris'] = array('admin/Admintask/get_task_detail');`

   note: Confirm your URI from routes.php

This will exclude the URL from CSRF validation.  You can learn more from [here](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/security.html?highlight=csrf_exclude_uris).

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 - onclick="refresh_detail(`<?php echo $your_id ?>`)"

Step 2 - set $config['cookie_secure'] in config file to FALSE if you're using HTTP.

Step 3 - set $config['csrf_protection'] = false;

Answer (score 0):

@Marcus you need to send CSRF token with your ajax code,like
 `data : {"TaskID" : id,"<?= $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>":"<?= $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>"}`